# Make material-ui v1 Button white by default

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui

`material-ui`'s `RaisedButton` was in the past [white by default](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/raised-button), if not `primary` or `secondary`. They have now changed it to be [grey by default](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/demos/buttons/).

I'm wondering what the cleanest way of making all those buttons white by default would be ?

I guess I could simply add some inline style or class and write the CSS to do it, but isn't there a way to do it with the official customization API?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the cleanest way of doing it, indeed using the overrides object, as mentioned by dan:

```
const myTheme = createMuiTheme({
  // other theme stuff
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      raised: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
      },
    },
  },
});
```